# How do get a simple localstack/localstack to work with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm trying to get a local docker instance of localstack/localstack to work with node.js aws-sdk library. But I can get a simple createTopic to work on an sns client.

I have started the docker image with this command and

> docker run -d -p 4567-4583:4567-4583  localstack/localstack

The code that I am running....

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'something',
  secretAccessKey: 'something',
  region:'us-east-1',
  logger: process.stdout
})

const sns = new AWS.SNS({endpoint:'http://localhost::4575'})
sns.createTopic({Name:'testing123'})
  .promise()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
```

And the error that is returned....

> [AWS sns 404 0.035s 0 retries] createTopic({ Name: 'testing123' }) {
>   404: null
>       at Request.extractError (/Users/t.smith/workspace/scratch/fake-sns-testing/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:52:29)
>       at Request.callListeners (/Users/t.smith/workspace/scratch/fake-sns-testing/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
>       at Request.emit (/Users/t.smith/workspace/scratch/fake-sns-testing/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
>       at Request.emit (/Users/t.smith/workspace/scratch/fake-sns-testing/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
>       at Request.transition (/Users/t.smith/workspace/scratch/fake-sns-testing/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
>       at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/t.smith/workspace/scratch/fake-sns-testing/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
>       at /Users/t.smith/workspace/scratch/fake-sns-testing/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
>       at Request. (/Users/t.smith/workspace/scratch/fake-sns-testing/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
>       at Request. (/Users/t.smith/workspace/scratch/fake-sns-testing/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
>       at Request.callListeners (/Users/t.smith/workspace/scratch/fake-sns-testing/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
>   message: null,   code: 404,   time: 2018-04-23T09:56:50.296Z,
>   requestId: undefined,   statusCode: 404,   retryable: false,
>   retryDelay: 95.466505112399 }

I would like to hear from anyone who has successfully managed to work with a localstack/localstack docker image with node.js. Thanks.

Comment: Could you try replacing the endpoint by `'http://localhost:4575'` (without double :)

Comment: Thanks, make an answer to claim your prize

Comment: Thomas, thats a serious typo :-). I was about to post an answer and then read the comments. Since @hugodby posted this first, he deserves to post the answer and claim the points.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is to correct the SNS endpoint by removing double `:` in the url.